# Force Excel charts in Word documents to use system separator in Windows 11

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, charts, windows-11

For my work, I need to use different decimal separators in Word (",") and Excel (".").
Previously, I could set that up as follows (Windows 10):

1. For Word documents, set "," as decimal separator through System settings (Windows: Control panel, Regional settings)
2. For Excel: set "." as decimal separator through Settings (File, Options, Advanced, uncheck Use system separators)

This setup stopped working when I changed laptop and upgraded to Windows 11. Excel charts now keep Excel separator instead of using system separator when pasted into Word documents.

The only way I can change Excel charts in Word separators now is by changing Excel setting to Use system separators (which is a big inconvenience for my work). Is there any way I can force the old behavior?

Comment: Are you using the same Office version as before? How did you insert the Excel graph into Word? Have you played around with the different copy-paste option (e.g. paste as object). You can get the "paste special" menu by pressing alt - E - S.

Comment: I suspect the default paste behavior might have changed. Can you check how your docs were pasted on the old laptop still? E.g. as picture, as object? If "as object" can you see the name of the object from the "paste special" menu?

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can try to make use of the Windows language bar shortcut key (windows + spacebar, or left alt+shift) to toggle between two "language/regional" configurations.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response.
1. I used Office 2016 (same as before) then upgraded to Office 365. In both versions, the problem persisted.
2. None of the Paste special options worked for me. The default option is Microsoft Office Graphic Object (which is what I usually use) and other options are Bitmap and various different Picture formats. 
3. I regularly switch between English and Vietnamese keyboards but as far as I can see it doesn't help.

Comment: I repeated the same using Windows 10 and Office 365. Changed Excel decimal separator to "," (system is "."). Plotted a graph in Excel. CTRL + C copy, and CTRL + V in Word, which pasted the graph as a "Microsoft Office Graphic Object" and translated the decimal separator back to ".". It also makes a file link to the Excel data file (if you right click and "edit data" the original file will open). If however I choose "Microsoft Excel Chart Object" from the Paste special menu, it keeps the "," separator. Right-click "Binary Worksheet Object" > "Edit" opens the data in Excel but from the .docx

Comment: So on Windows 11, when you plainly "copy" the graph and "paste" into Word, then right-click, what options to edit the data do you have? Also after saving the Word document, click file > info. Do you have an option "Edit Links to Files" bottom right? I.e. has a file link been created? Note this option will not shown it you didn't save the file to disk. Also, if I paste as "Microsoft Excel Chart Object" there is no file link as the data is actually stored inside the docx file.

Comment: Thank you again!
1. What you described was my experience prior to upgrading to Windows 11. Everything worked fine then.
2. I do not have my work laptop here with me, but as far as I recall, the default option is Microsoft Office Graphic Object in Windows 11, and there is no Microsoft Excel Chart Object paste option.
3. I have not checked but I would assume there is a Link in Windows 11 as well (since the graph updated along the Excel file) - I would confirm this ASAP tomorrow.

Comment: Under Win 10, the default paste is "Microsoft Office Graphic Object". The data sits in the Excel file, but the graph is being made by Word, hence uses system settings. If you paste as "Microsoft Excel Chart Object", both the data and the graph sits inside an Excel object in the Word file. The graph is actually made by Excel so it uses its own settings.  Perhaps under Windows 11 one of this happened: a) default paste is the chart object and maybe graphic object is no longer available or b) Word is now aware of the Excel settings and rather uses it - unlikely though as its still the same version

Comment: Speaking of versions, my MSO365 is Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20128) 64-bit

Comment: 1. For plain Copy and Paste: Right-click -> Edit data -> There are two options, Edit data and Edit data in Excel, both of which open the Excel file when clicked.
2. There is an option to "Edit Links to Files"
3. I have tried all other Paste Special Option (including Microsoft Excel Chart Object), none of which worked.

Comment: Thats not good news. Probably Windows 11 with Office is more hyper aware of localisation settings. So they thought they fixed an inconsistency/bug. You were using the "bug" as a convenience. Perhaps you need to use Libre Calc or Google sheet as alternative spreadsheet program, or at least a go between?

Comment: Language bar option: can you not add an additional english language (like UK or South Africa), then edit the advance regional settings in the old control panel (not new Settings) while the new language is selected. Change the decimal separator. Paste graph as image. Toggle back to your usual language.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I agree that it seems I was using a bug as a convenience.  Unfortunately, your suggestions seem to be more inconvenient than switching Excel's decimal settings for me :(.